# Regex lookahead. Find word without .min. in string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to replace a link in a html file with regex and nodejs. I want to replace links without a .min.js extension.

For example, it should match "common.js" but not "common.min.js"

Here's what I've tried:

```
let htmlOutput = html.replace(/common\.(?!min)*js/g, common.name);
```

I think this negative lookahead should work but it doesn't match anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe just `let htmlOutput = html.replace(/\bcommon\.js\b/g, common.name);`? `(?!min)*js` makes no sense.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It [works](https://regex101.com/r/zf6RHX/1). Also, see https://jsfiddle.net/wxvL9m7p/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Confusing. It must be another issue preventing a match. I'll take a look and get back to you.

Comment: What is in `common.name`, BTW?

Comment: It's from WebPack. A string containing the js filename with a generated contenthash for cache busting

Comment: Ok, if it can contain `$`, use `common.name.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$')`. But you should check what you are doing because the regex I shared must work.

Comment: Your regex is correct but it still doesn't replace the string in my html. Not sure why. I'll do some tests

Comment: Are you sure you are assigning the new value after replacement to the variable?

Comment: Turns out is was an assignment issue with my file variable. Works perfectly now. Thank you so much

Comment: Will somebody please formulate a proper answer, please? :) So we can up-vote...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, could I ask for help again? The regex doesn't fully fufill my use case. Searching for the word 'common.js' will work the first time. How do I search the second time when the string will look like 'common.9132423487928.js'? I tried .* which predictably brought me common.345345345.js and common.456456456.min.js

Comment: Found it. I'll post an answer below crediting you @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @virolino I posted the right [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56464824/3832970).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(?!min)*js` part is corrupt: you should not quantify zero-width assertions like lookaheads (they do not consume text so quantifiers after them are treated either as user errors or are ignored). Since `js` does not start with `min` this lookahead even without a quantifier is redundant.

If you want to match a string with a whole word `common`, then having any chars and ending with `.js` but not `.min.js` you need

```
/\bcommon\b(?!.*\.min\.js$).*\.js$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A4kqo7/1).

**Details**:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `common` - a substring
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?!.*\.min\.js$)` - immediately to the right, there should not be any 0 or more chars followed with `.min.js` at the end of the string
- `.*` - any 0 or more chars
- `\.js` - a `.js` substring
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Here, we likely can find a simple expression to pass any char except new lines and `.`, after the word `common`, followed by `.js`:

```
common([^\.]+)?\.js
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PgJ2fr/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The end regex I'm using is `/\bcommon[^min]+js\b/g`

This will find the word common with any amount of chracters afterword except if those characters contain the word `min`and ending in `js` allowing me to replace scripts on my html page like:

script src="~/dist/common.js"

OR

script src="~/dist/common.9cf5748e0e7fc2928a07.js"

Thanks to Wiktor Stribiżew for helping me.

Comment: You are rather wrong. `\bcommon[^min]+js\b` matches `common`  followed with 1 or more chars other than `m`, `i`, `n` followed with `js` substring. So you need `\bcommon(?:(?!min).)*?js\b` I guess, judging by your description. Or `\bcommon\b(?!\S*\.min\.js\b)\S*\.js\b`